# ElasticSearch and Master/Slave Configuration

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch and I am wondering if it is actually possible setup a configuration like this:

1. I have 10 slave nodes that contain the same data at a specific time (Time-0)
2. I write a totally new set of data to the "master" (this set of data it is supposed to replace totally the data of the 10 slaves, not just updating)
3. I switch off the master and the 10 slaves have the new set of data (replacing the data at Time-0)

If it is possible, any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but not really in the master/slave mindset you are thinking of.

You'd accomplish this with index aliases: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

1) Index "current" with an index alias called "live"

2) Index "new" that you write your data to. Use an index alias "beta" to generalize.

3) Perform and atomic index alias swap which points the "live" alias at the "new" index.

You can further play tricks with replica counts, so that before the swap, the new index gets replicas on all the servers.